# How to scale Gatsby to 1000s of static files without running out of memory?

Tags: gatsby

I'm developing a React web app with [Gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby). After adding over a 1000 static markdown files, the build process requires a lot of memory. I'm running the builds under AWS Lambda, and I've started to get SIGKILLs once the memory limit of 1536MB is exhausted.

How could Gatsby builds be scaled to thousands of files without requiring more and more memory? According to the [developer](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/363#issuecomment-234675018), it should be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Gatsby pulls all site content, css, js into memory while doing a build. Potentially there's ways to reduce the amount of memory Gatsby uses but currently the best way to reduce your memory usage would be to split the site into identical but separate sites. I.e. keep the templates/css the same but 1000s of Markdown files into multiple sites and build each separately in sequence.

Comment: A few questions come to mind with this solution. Can I still somehow access  the full list of files (this.props.route.pages) or would I need to create my own API for that? Also, the default template uses /bundle.js?t=${BUILD_TIME} for cache invalidation; I suppose that might cause problems in multiple sequential builds?

Comment: Not to necro this, but couldn't you, potentially, leverage [setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType) to "expand" the node at load time? (Coming across this post  randomly, but got curious)

Answer (score 4):

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/.bin/gatsby build
```

That's how I ran the benchmark when I was trying to make webpack faster. Was building upwards of 5000+ markdown posts.

Comment: I tried with --max-old-space-size=1024 under Lambda, and it seems that the build process now completes successfully with 1500+ .md files! It takes a lot of time and the maximum timeout of 300s will eventually be reached, but I believe that technically this solution solved my immediate problem.

Comment: Well, it seems that my success is a bit random. I sometimes still get Lambda SIGKILLs with --max-old-space-size=1024. When using --max-old-space-size=512, I get `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory` from the Gatsby build process. So this doesn't seem to solve the problem in a reliable way.

Comment: Okay, I also tried with --max-old-space-size=768 and it seems to work just within the limits of AWS Lambda. The build process completes successfully with these stats: `Duration: 158285.52 ms Billed Duration: 158300 ms Memory Size: 1536 MB Max Memory Used: 1474 MB `

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling the BABEL_CACHE environment variable. I have run into problems on AWS lambda, too, and moved to Docker based builds.

Comment: According to the docs at at https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/, the way to disable caching is to set BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1. I'll try that.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately the build process was still killed under Lambda by SIGKILL, indicating memory is still maxed out.

Comment: On closer examination, I think BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE only affects the cache that is saved in temporary files on disk. So it would not have any effect on memory usage.